# Manipulations with Dictionary. How to optimize the code and make it more proffesional?

Tags: c#, dictionary, optimization, refactoring, code-inspection

`Main` is added for checks, the war field is `GetMostFrequentNextWords`. How to optimize the code? What data types can be better instead of `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>`? Are there any problems with the usage of this data type?  Is my code easy to read? I am searching for all my problems

#### The task:

N-gram it's N adjacent words in one sentence. for example, from the text: "She stood up. Then she left." you can take the next 2-grams "she stood", "stood up", "then she" and "she left", But not the next case "up then". And 3-grams "she stood up" and "then she left", but not the case "stood up then".

with a list of sentences (the list is consist of words, that are assembled in the list of sentences) create a vocabulary of the most frequent continuations of 2-grams and 3-grams. It's the vocabulary, in which all possible beginnings of 2-grams and 3-grams are Keys, and the Values are their most frequent continuations. if there are few continuations with equal frequency, you should store a string that is smaller ( with help of String.CompareOrdinal ).

**Example** Text: "a b c d. b c d. e b c a d." You should get the next vocabulary:

1 "a": "b"

2 "b": "c"

3 "c": "d"

4 "e": "b"

5 "a b": "c"

6 "b c": "d"

7 "e b": "c"

8 "c a": "d"

From 2-grams "a b" and "a d" that met once, there is only one pair in Dictionary  "a": "b",  because it's the smaller one. From the next two 2-grams  "c d" и "c a" There is only one most frequent pair "c": "d".  And from 3-grams "b c d" and "b c a" Next pair is in vocabulary as the most frequent one "b c": "d".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    public static class SentencesParserTask
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //a b c d. b c d. e b c a d.
            var list = new List<List<string>>();
            list.Add(new List<string>());
            list[0].Add("a");
            list[0].Add("b");
            list[0].Add("c");
            list[0].Add("d");
            list.Add(new List<string>());
            list[1].Add("b");
            list[1].Add("c");
            list[1].Add("d");
            list.Add(new List<string>());
            list[2].Add("e");
            list[2].Add("b");
            list[2].Add("c");
            list[2].Add("a");
            list[2].Add("d");

            Console.WriteLine("The origin text : \n" );
            foreach (var sentence in list)
            {
                foreach(var word in sentence)
                {
                    Console.Write(" " + word);
                }
                Console.Write(".");
            }

            Console.Write("\n\n ");
            Console.WriteLine("Expected output: \n1 a: b \n2 b: c \n3 c: d \n4 e: b \n5 a b: c \n6 b c: d \n7 e b: c \n8 c a: d \n\n ");

            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(GetMostFrequentNextWords(list));
            int index = 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Your output (THE ORDER ISNT IMPORTANT) :");
            foreach (var keyValuePair in dictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(index++ + " " + keyValuePair.Key + ": " + keyValuePair.Value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> GetMostFrequentNextWords(List<List<string>> text)
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var helpDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < text[i].Count; j++)
                {
                    if (text[i].Count - j >= 3)
                    {
                        string keyTwoWords = text[i][j] + " " + text[i][j + 1];
                        if (!helpDictionary.ContainsKey(keyTwoWords))
                            helpDictionary[keyTwoWords] = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                        if (!helpDictionary[keyTwoWords].ContainsKey(text[i][j + 2]))
                            helpDictionary[keyTwoWords][text[i][j + 2]] = 0;

                        helpDictionary[keyTwoWords][text[i][j + 2]]++;
                    }

                    if (text[i].Count - j >= 2)
                    {
                        if (!helpDictionary.ContainsKey(text[i][j]))
                            helpDictionary[text[i][j]] = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                        if (!helpDictionary[text[i][j]].ContainsKey(text[i][j + 1]))
                            helpDictionary[text[i][j]][text[i][j + 1]] = 0;

                        helpDictionary[text[i][j]][text[i][j + 1]]++;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, int>> keyValuePair in helpDictionary)
            {
                if (!result.ContainsKey(keyValuePair.Key))
                    result[keyValuePair.Key] = "";
                int maxFrequencyCount = 0;
                string maxFrequencyString = "";
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> keyValuePairInternal in keyValuePair.Value)
                {
                    if ((keyValuePairInternal.Value > maxFrequencyCount) || ((keyValuePairInternal.Value == maxFrequencyCount) &&
                        (string.CompareOrdinal(maxFrequencyString, keyValuePairInternal.Key) > 0)))
                    {
                        result[keyValuePair.Key] = keyValuePairInternal.Key;
                        maxFrequencyCount = keyValuePairInternal.Value;
                        maxFrequencyString = keyValuePairInternal.Key;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't mind helping with a problem if you've tried it yourself, I can't see any effort to solve this.

Comment: First off: if the code is actually working and you're looking for a code-reviewv, you should use https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Second: please be specific in your goal. What specific problem are you trying to solve? We're definitly not scanning your entire code to scan for potential problems with it. How do you define "better"? Easy to read IMHO is pretty opinion-based as well, so you won't get any definitive answer to that.

Comment: @DubDub , I solved the original problem and i want to improve my understanding, and my code skills. My code is working

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, I am a newbie here so I investigate my opportunities. I formulated my question as well as I could for now, but I'll become better at understanding the concept of the site. I need time and experience

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain about easy-to-read question. Yes, it's pretty unclear. But for example, some variables cannot describe their aims or something like that. Difficult structures that one can change to more simple ones. Is my choice for this task of data type good? I guess that's a pretty normal question. But yeah, I am bad at this platform anyway for now

Comment: If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".